# Deep Learning accuracy vs Confusion Matrix accuracy

Tags: deep-learning, machine-learning-model, accuracy, confusion-matrix

I am working on deep learning with fer2013 dataset.

After training the model I got **val_precision: 0.9168** (precision: 0.8492)

```
Epoch 67/100
238/238 [==============================] - 31s 130ms/step - loss: 1.5087 - tp: 2622.4142 - fp: 474.9121 - tn: 45584.3013 - fn: 5054.1213 - accuracy: 0.8972 - precision: 0.8492 - recall: 0.3410 - auc: 0.9042 - prc: 0.6758 - val_loss: 0.9754 - val_tp: 1389.0000 - val_fp: 126.0000 - val_tn: 22698.0000 - val_fn: 2415.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.9046 - **val_precision: 0.9168** - val_recall: 0.3651 - val_auc: 0.9235 - val_prc: 0.7276
Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.
Epoch 00067: early stopping
```

But when I output the "Confusion Matrix" I get precision of 0.13 - 0.18 ...
[image]

I have some misunderstanding - why is my precision so different ?

Is this confusion matrix part has errors ?

Here is my notebook -> https://www.kaggle.com/code/prilia/emotion-recognition-with-resnet50-7emotions/notebook

Please help

Comment: Isn't that an $F_1$ score, not an accuracy?

Comment: hi, I updated the question.

Comment: I assume that the confusion matrix shows performance on the test set, right? This looks like overfitting to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"precision: 0.8492" is on the training data. "val_precision: 0.9168" is on the validation data. "Confusion Matrix" is on the test data.

The precision values are different because they are three different data sets. One possible reason that the values are smaller on the test data set is that the model is overfitting to the training dataset.